# .NET Assembly .DLL encryption and usage in teams

Tags: c#, security, digital-signature

I have a relatively large C# project. I want to allow other developers to collaborate with me on the project. But I'm afraid they will copy the source code verbatim. I want to protect my code. Is there a way I could grant collaborators usage of existing .dll's w/o them able to read the source code? Or grant them temporary access to the .dll's and later when they roll off the project just disable their ability to use the .dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, you can give other people DLLs without access to the source code. In most situations like this, you would obfuscate the dll (many tools to do this, I would start with the Dotfuscator included with Visual Studio) so they can't decompile it.

If you want them to be able to see the source, there isn't much you can do to avoid them copying it, same with "disabling their ability to use it". If they have a copy of the file, there isn't much you can stop them from doing (technologically speaking). The only security I can think of for that would be to have all public functions check against some server before executing (thus making the DLL useless if you have that server not allow them to run), but that isn't 100% and would make for a terrible experience for end-users of the code.

Comment: No need to make every function check.  You only would need to do it once either on load, or on first function invokation.  You can then cache the value that tells you if license was validated or not.

Comment: How would the DLL know if it is loaded? And if every function didn't check, couldn't the using code just call the non-checking functions? I would be very interested to know how to do this at the assembly level.

Comment: Ah, let me clarify. I meant every function need not call license server; it'll need to check local flag to see if license is granted.  So 1st function incurs big expense of making remote call, sets the flag, and all others check the flag to see if they're allowed to run.  As to DLL knowing it is being loaded, I don't believe there's a direct way (unlike unmanaged where one can use `DllMain()` for this). However one can use static constructor for major type(s), and IIRC, if static constructor throws, then type is not loaded and can't be used, thus effectively disabling assembly (yes, bit hacky)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think we are in agreement now :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to LordTakkera's answer, the part about licensing.

A variation on licensing is to only allow DLL to run for something like 30 days or so, and the DLL would check local time (or hit a time server) to see if it is past due.  Then you can supply time-limited DLLs to your collaborators, and keep them updated every month with a newer copy while they're staying on the project.  This is less involved as it won't require to have a license server and maintaining license keys, and necessary cryptology to make sure someone isn't able to fake a license, but is also less secure as clock can be easily manipulated, and updating everyone with monthly build would be quite a discouragement from participation in the project...   Oh those trade-off...

Comment: +1 This is another good way to "time-out" a dll, with the tradeoffs mentioned.